# New wpf themes for specific visual styles

Tags: wpf, styles, microsoft-metro, themes

What I am wondering is if I can add default wpf themes for different visual styles (I can use 3rd party visual styles because my system is patched).

For example, `PresentationFramework.Aero` automatically gets used for aero, `PresentationFramework.Luna` automatically gets used for the XP luna theme, so I am wondering if I can make a new assembly, like `PresentationFramework.Metro` for a visual style called `Metro.msstyles`.

Would this work? And how would I go about doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, it should work...

I think the theme assembly is picked based on the theme info returned by [GetCurrentThemeName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773365%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For instance, for Aero with normal color, it returns:

```
pszThemeFileName = "Aero"
pszColorBuff = "NormalColor"
pszSizeBuff = "NormalSize"
```

However I'm not sure this function works properly for all themes (IIRC, it didn't work for the Zune theme in Windows XP), so make sure it returns the expected values for Metro before you start creating your theme assembly. If it does work, you just need to create an assembly with an XAML dictionary that contains styles for all standard controls.

Comment: Ok. How exactly would I go about doing that, then? Because I don't quite know how all that works.

Comment: @AlexanderKvenvolden, here's an example of how to use the GetCurrentThemeName API: https://gist.github.com/3653097 (just call ThemeInfo.Current to get info about current theme). And I just checked, it seems to work with non-default styles as well (e.g. Zune theme)